# Removing a html class won't detach removed class functionality using jQuery removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I need to have an accordion element disabled until the user enters some stuff in another accordion element. I have this setting for the HTML:

```
       ...
        <ul>
          <li><a id="subject_link" href="#subject"> Paciente </a></li>
          <li><a id="general_link" href="#general" class="disabled">Información General</a></li>
        </ul>
       ...
```

It has a bunch of other elements but to make a point I think this will suffice.

Notice that general link has a "disabled" that is meant to prevent the user to go navigate into that part of the HTML without doing some stuff first. This is currently being done like this:

```
  $(".disabled").click( function(){
$( "#subject_link").click()// Scroll screen to target element
alert("You need to enter subject ID first");
 });
```

The above code alerts the user to enter the ID first and returns him to the corresponding accordion element. Then, when the user enters the subject id, I trigger the class removal:

```
  if($("#tab0").valid()){
    $.post( url , values);
    // alert( "Data Loaded: " + str );
    $("#general_link").removeClass("disabled");
    $("#general_link").click();
```

The above removes the class successfully (both the markup "class=disabled" that no longer appears and styling suggest that) but clicking on the now not-disabled element still triggers the function meant for ".disabled" (alerts the user for missing ID and navigates to corresponding element).

What am I missing here???

Comment: `.disabled` is only a CSS reference to that element which by removing it,doesn't mean you're removing the event `click` to that element. below is the proper way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use event delegation so when an event occurs the target element will be re-checked again against the selector. So use this instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".disabled", function(){
    $( "#subject_link").click()// Scroll screen to target element
    alert("You need to enter subject ID first");
});
```

**NOTE:** the `document` here could be any of the parents of `.disabled` element. The closest that parent is the more quicker the ckeck will be. (I don't know about the rest of your HTML, so if you have that UL inside a DIV that can be selected then put that selector instead of `document` in the above code)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.off()` [method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to detach that functionality:

```
$("#general_link.disabled").off("click");
$("#general_link").removeClass("disabled");
```